# How does one intercept the "Page Not Found" error in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am writing an app containing the WebView. and I want to put in some functionality to interecpt the "Page Not Found" message in case the content I am trying to show in my app ever is offline or for some other reason unreachable.
I tried using the onReceivedError() but to no avail. Unless perhaps my syntax is wrong, but if soI don't see the error. can someone help?

code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.somesite.net");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        //TO DO - do something else in here if the site is down
        }
      });


}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "I tried using the onReceivedError() but to no avail."

Comment: @CommonsWare
by that i mean in the code sample where you see my commented "//TO DO" line, I have tried using a toast message and i have tried using mWebView.loadUrl() and sending it to an alternate URL. the code executes without error, but i still get the "Page Not Found" instead of the toast message or redirected Url.

Comment: The problem may be that you are setting two `WebViewClient` objects. Otherwise, AFAIK, `onReceivedError()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The WebViewClient should be set before you load the url.

Comment: Actually, WebViewClient worked just fine set as it is as a means to prevent a clicked link from opening the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this.  onReceivedError() works fine.  You will receive a -2 when the error happens.